# Several (two) Flask objects in same application

Tags: python, flask

I need two http servers in same python application (with two differents ports 8081 and 8082):
One for a video stream coming from webcam and sent to WebBrowser;
Second one for command (quality, filter, etc.)
I don't succeed to define two Flask objects, because 'app.run' is blocking.
Is it possible, or do I need to use a Flask and a BaseHTTPServer ?
Best regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, Solution is :
app.run( threaded=True, ...)
Now it is possible to process at same time several requests, for exemple one for video streaming, other for video parameter tuning and so on.

Answer (score 1):

You can call [`Flask.run(port=8081)`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/api/#flask.Flask.run), but not in the same process (as `run()` is indeed blocking).

You should create different `Flask` instances for each service, and run them in separate commands (although one can be run in background):

**run.sh**

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh
# Runs in background:
python app_webcam.py &
# Runs in foreground
python app_command.py
```

**app_webcam.py**

```
# ... (setup you Flask app)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(port=8081)
```

**app_command.py**

```
# ... (setup you Flask app)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(port=8082)
```

Comment: yes, but if I want to easily apply commands received from one interface on the other one...without messaging etc...